# Проверка состояния сервисов в Ansible

Tags: python, ansible

Добрый день. Хотелось бы узнать, с помощью какого модуля можно проверить состояние сервисов на удаленных хостах с выводом на экран терминала? Благодарю за внимание.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отдельного модуля для того, чтобы узнать состояние нет (по крайней мере в текущей версии Ansible 2.3).

Можно использовать `command`/`shell` и команду от вашей ОС с выключенными предупреждениями (`warn: no`). [Пример](https://ansibledaily.com/avoid-ansible-command-warnings/):

```
- name: get list of services without Ansible warning
  shell: "service --status-all 2>&1 | awk {'print $4'}"
  args:
    warn: false # set warn=false to prevent warning
  register: services_list
```

Comment: Спасибо, я рассматривал этот вариант)